# Change size of highcharts points on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I want the points of my graph to be larger on mobile to make them easier to click on.  They are set as circles with a radius of 4 in my javascript file, but I want to set them with a radius of 8 when the window size is below 500px.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/593rknnv/.  I know I'm not correctly targeting the points here, but I have that problem solved in my own code.  As you can see, when the window is resized the points change color, but I don't know what attribute to change to affect the size.

My real code:

```
@media(max-width: 500px){
    html{
        background-color: blue !important;
    }
    #container {
        width: 1200px !important;
    }

    g.highcharts-markers.highcharts-tracker path{
        fill: blue !important;
        radius: 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    if ($(window).width() < 500) {           
       chart.options.plotOptions.spline.marker.radius = 8;
       chart.series[0].update();
    }
    else {
       chart.options.plotOptions.spline.marker.radius = 4;
       chart.series[0].update();
    }
});
```

You must change **plotOptions.spline.marker.radius** to 8 in chart options, not in **CSS**. `$( window ).resize` checks for every change in size of the page, then sets the radius of the markers accordingly. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/593rknnv/1/)

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated

Comment: @thumbtackthief is it so hard to comment or accept the answer?